# Unable to set ggmap boundary

Tags: r

I am new to R, I am trying to plot coordinates on the map. Example of my coordinates:

```
Longitude  Latitude
-0.113767  51.517372
-0.098062  51.517583
-0.098062  51.517584
-0.098062. 51.517585
-0.097053. 51.518266
-0.097601  51.520707
-0.098062  51.517588
-0.097601  51.520709
-0.097601  51.5207010
-0.096348. 51.5154711
-0.097562  51.5188612
-0.097053  51.5182613
-0.097053  51.5182614
-0.097053. 51.5182615
-0.097053. 51.5182616
```

These are my codes:

```
Tryggmap <- get_map("London, UK", maptype = "terrain", zoom = 14)
ggmap(Tryggmap) + geom_point(
  data = TryTry,
  aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude),
  color = "red",
  size = 1
) + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.13, -0.07), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(51.50, 51.53), expand = c(0, 0))
```

But it produced something like this.

[image]